# Entering Random numbers to a 2D array with no Duplicates

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I want to enter 64 different numbers into an 8*8 array but I am having problems...

```
int[,] check = new int[8, 8];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[,] T = new int[8, 8];
        for (int i = 0; i <=7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <=7; j++)
            {
                int num = rnd.Next(1, 64);
                check[i, j] = num;
                while (num != check[i,j])
                {
                    T[i, j] = num;

                }
                Console.Write("{0}\t", T[i, j]);
            }
            Console.Write("\n\n");
        }
```

Comment: As written the code can never complete since it can only generate 63 random numbers.  You don't actually want random numbers, you know you want 1..64.  You want a random *order*.  Google "c# random shuffle" to find the correct way to do this.

Comment: You may use `HashSet` to check if random number is already used or not. If not insert it into the 2d array and save it.

Comment: random object provides double value .You can not stored in int .So convert it into integer                           int num = Convert.ToInt32(rnd.Next(1, 64)*1000);

Answer (score 1):

Try following which randomly assigned the numbers 0 to 63 to the array :

```
    class Program
    {
        const int ROWS = 8;
        const int COLS = 8;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            int[] values = Enumerable.Range(0, ROWS * COLS)
                .Select(x => new { number = x, rand = rnd.Next()})
                .OrderBy(x => x.rand)
                .Select(x => x.number).ToArray();

            int[,] T = new int[ROWS, COLS];

            int count = 0;
            for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
            {
                for(int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
                {
                    T[row, col] = values[count++];
                }
            }

        }
```